# Can we auto generate nunit test cases in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nunit

I have to write nunit test cases for the huge application made of aspx.cs files tat too in Visual studio 2013 professional , can I auto generate the test cases if possible with this version or any other better ideas to write test cases, as it contains more number of dependencies & complexities

Comment: No, your going to have to actually write the tests yourself

Comment: Also, please don't ask the [same question multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905714/nunit-testcases-creation-integration)

Comment: I don't think you have thought this through. How do you expect software to auto-generate test cases?? How is some software going to know what tests should be performed and what results would be considered pass or fail? Did you first write an AI which can fully understand all your written requirements (not to mention all the implicit ones which are probably still in your head) and use them to create meaningful tests??? Automated testing is a great time-saver for validating builds, but you can't automate the automation. A human being still has to define what tests should be carried out.

Answer (score 2):

you are lucky, because in fact you can (partially).
It is true the guys above wrote. You can not let software test software because it doesn't know what the requirements oft a unit under test are.

BUT you can use Test Case generation tools such as devmate, which is a visual studio extension

devmate is gathering the input values of your testmethod and providing a test model editor.
You than have to create input values, testcases and output values considering the requirments and than >>> **you can auto generate testcode**.

here is a link to the extension in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AutomatedSoftwareTestingGmbH.ASTdevmate1).